# Angular server side rendering template (.cshtml) parse error with escape symbols

Tags: javascript, c#, html, angular, razor

I have C# razor *.cshtml template file and would like to use it for Angular (5) server side rendering.

**C# .cshtml snippet:**

```
@helper RenderLookupComponent()
{
    <list-lookup 
          [data]="getLookupData('@Model.LookupSourceType')"
          [lookupType]="'@Model.LookupSourceType'">
    </list-lookup>
}
```

Everything works fine until **'@Model.LookupSourceType'** value is not contains escape symbol (**'\'**), for e.g. when **@Model.LookupSourceType = 'SomeType\'**

**Angular template parser Error:**

```
[error]: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column # in [getLookupData('SomeType\')]
```

At first glance, it looks like ordinary issue, actually it can be solve by replacing all '\' to '\'. (`@Model.LookupSourceType.Replace(@"\", @"\\"`)).

**Q:** But i believe there should be more elegant, universal approaches to solve such kind of problems.
The approach that can handles all possible scenario for different kind of escape symbols

Please share your experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved with using `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.LookupSourceType)`